# How to make excel ignore characters when it counts sum of values in a row that contains the characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, row 1 has A1 = 1, B1 = 2, and C1 = "N/A". 
I want to count sum of three cells, but without remove the C1 out of the formula.

If I simply use =Sum(A1:C1), the result would be an error. So, how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `SUMIF` (better choice if your range contains only `#N/A` error):

```
=SUMIF(A1:C1,"<>#N/A")
```

or, alternatively, if your range contains not only `#N/A` but also other errors:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:C1),A1:C1))
```

This is an *array formula*, so type the formula then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula.

Comment: Another option: `=SUM(IFERROR(A1:A3,0))` (also an array formula)

Comment: absolutelly, it's even shorter:)

Answer (score 0):

`=sum(A1:A5)` [for regular cells]
`=sum(A1,D1,G1)` [while picking up different cells)